# Queue up arrays or write Queue to more dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

I've got arrays of floats with 4 floats each. I'd like to queue them up to later write the content of the queue to a file. I use this code:

In my "MasterScript.cs":

```
public static Queue <float> my_pointsQ = new Queue <float> ();
```

Fill queue with content:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points_count; ++i)
            {
                MasterScript.my_pointsQ.Enqueue(my_points[i]);

            }
```

write queue to file:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file)){
    foreach (float point in MasterScript.my_pointsQ) 
    writer.WriteLine (point);
}
```

It works, but I got all the floats one per line. I'd like to have four floats per line as the original `m_points`are arrays of four floats each... 
Is there a possibility to queue up arrays of floats? (When I delete the `<float>` in the MasterScript and adress points by `foreach (object point in MasterScript.my_pointsQ)` I got single lines too.)

Or is there a way to copy my queue to a four-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just queue up the arrays by changing the Queue type to

```
public static Queue <float[]> my_pointsQ = new Queue <float[]> ();
```

See this: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ECMdf)

Comment: Thank you very much :) This is what I need

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to store the arrays in the queue

```
public static Queue <float[]> my_pointsQ = new Queue <float[]> ();
```

Then you should be able to write them like this

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    foreach (float[] point in MasterScript.my_pointsQ) 
         writer.WriteLine (string.Join(",",point);
}
```

I used a "," as my separator but you can leave it blank, or change it to whatever you want.